# ROS kinetic: ImportError: No module named terminal_color

Tags: python, catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I a trying to compile a catkin package that shall generate some ROS messages. Unfortunately I get to this error an can't get it resolved:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/geneus/cmake/../../../lib/geneus/gen_eus.py", line 39, in <module>
    import geneus
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geneus/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . geneus_main import *
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geneus/geneus_main.py", line 43, in <module>
    from catkin import terminal_color
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/terminal_color.py", line 2, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.terminal_color import *  # noqa
ImportError: No module named terminal_color
```

Some days ago I updated my ROS packages and before it was working.

Here is some more information:

```
$ dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg-modules
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg-modules
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg-modules/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg-modules/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/topological_order.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/metapackage.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/tool_detection.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/terminal_color.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog_generator.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cmake.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog_generator_vcs.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/CMakeLists.txt.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/package.xml.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/metapackage.cmake.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/python_setup.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/group_dependency.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/workspace_vcs.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/group_membership.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/prepare_release.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/create_pkg.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/test_changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/generate_changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/tag_changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/find_pkg.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/package_version.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_version.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/condition.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/rospack.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/workspaces.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.8.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.8.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.8.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.8.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.8.egg-info/requires.txt


$ sudo dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.8.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.8.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.8.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.8.egg-info/entry_points.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.8.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.8.egg-info/requires.txt
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/catkin_find_pkg
/usr/bin/catkin_create_pkg
/usr/bin/catkin_test_changelog
/usr/bin/catkin_prepare_release
/usr/bin/catkin_package_version
/usr/bin/catkin_tag_changelog
/usr/bin/catkin_generate_changelog
```

I just reinstalled ros completely without success.

What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301702/ros-kinetic:-importerror:-no-module-named-terminal_color/) by [inspire](https://answers.ros.org/users/28884/inspire/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-08-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-27**:
I believe this is a duplicate of #q294780. Can you please check?

**Comment by [inspire](https://answers.ros.org/users/28884/inspire/) on 2018-08-27**:
you might be right although I am on ROS kinetic and not melodic. Also python-catkin-pkg and python-catkin-pkg-modules are up to date which is the solution of the accepted answer in the other question. Pip also tells me the package is up to date with "pip install --upgrade catkin_pkg_modules".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the current release of `catkin` as well as `catkin_pkg` this will not be a problem. As suggested before you likely have an older version of `catkin_pkg` installed via `pip`. You should uninstall the pip installed package and only use the Debian package.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0